# How to serve static html files using Web Servlet?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, controller, static-site

I have two static websites located in two separate local directories.

I also have a secured web app with spring mvc. There are two users, each user is related to a different website.

I want to serve the relevant website/pages for each authenticated user from the same url.

How can i do that? Can i use custom Servlet/Controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements are like you have a Web app for authentication and after authentication and authorisation you want to redirect to another application which is hosted in another server. You could use controller for that in spring and depends upon the logic you can have different views

Comment: I don't want to run another server. I want to show the html page from the current page. Say address/myfile.html will simply load the static file myfile.html and show it to the user

Comment: Thats possible and you can configure the view in spring controller